# N nested while loops with different index in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a short example code which is made out of 3 nested while loops with the different indices i, j and k. The code prints out every 3-digit combination where i>j>k. I want to rewrite this code using a recursive function (or any other function which works for this), so I could change a parameter in the function to make the same thing but with a 4-digit combination (which would need 4 nested while loops).

```
i = 4
while i >= 0:
    j = i - 1
    while j >= 0:
        k = j - 1
        while k >= 0:
            print(str(k) + str(j) + str(i))
            k -= 1
        j -= 1
    i -= 1
```

The problem is when creating a recursive function that it uses the same index for every while loop and I can't check any relations anymore.

I there a way to get this working? I don't need to do this using a recursive function, but I figured it would somehow be the fastest way.

So any function that could recreate the following outputs for n=3 and n=2 would probably work.

n=3:

```
234
134
034
124
024
014
123
023
013
012
```

n=2:

```
34
24
14
04
23
13
03
12
02
01
```

Comment: I tried it with `i = 2` I got `012`

Comment: This is correct, because the possible numbers for i, j and k are no only {0,1,2} and we look for all the possible combination where i>j>k, which is only one with i=2, j=1 and k=0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uses the same mechanic as the previous answer, but is much more easier to understand, and compact.

I replaced the i with a list, because choosing digits that way would be much easier, you can also do range(5) in the array argument if you want.

how does it work?

1. basically combinations by default, acquires the possible combinations for the array provided, to the number of digits, n.
2. for example for n = 4, combinations return [(0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 2, 4), (0, 1, 3, 4), (0, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4)]
3. the rest of the function is for formatting the output, to what your program similarly outputs.

How does itertools.combinations() work?
This tool returns the  length subsequences of elements from the input iterable.

Combinations are emitted in lexicographic sorted order. So, if the input iterable is sorted, the combination tuples will be produced in sorted order.

```
import itertools
def combination(array, n):
    comb = itertools.combinations(array, n)
    return '\n'.join(["".join(list(map(str, val))) for val in comb])

print(combination([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 2)) # n=2
print(combination(range(5), 3)) # n=3
print(combination([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 4)) # n=4
```

Outputs:

```
# n = 2
01
02
03
04
12
13
14
23
24
34

# n = 3
012
013
014
023
024
034
123
124
134
234

# n = 4
0123
0124
0134
0234
1234
```

Comment: That's helping alot. I think I could use this in my code already, but I still want to understand some basic things here. How is the function itertools.combinations getting the output? So basically what's happening when I call the function?

Comment: You use combinations when the order of the things you are choosing does not matter and you have a limited set of choices. Let's say you are going to choose 3 people to go to the movies from your friends and you have 4 people to choose from. Let's call them A, B, C, and D. Choosing A first, B second and D third is basically the same thing as choosing B first, D second, and A third, since you will go to the movies with the same people in the end. So the number of possibilities you have is:

{A,B,C} {A,B,D} {A,C,D} {B,C,D} => 4

Comment: if this helped you, you can upvote and mark as solution.

Comment: But how does combinations gets these possibilities? Because that's exactly what I wanted to implement by myself without using any library.

Comment: check [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Answer (score 0):

Using the module itertools you can use the "combinations" tool to find combinations in a range of numbers/letters.

```
def findCombonation(high,length):
    import itertools

    if length > 0:
        combination = (itertools.combinations(range(0,high+1), length))
        for i in combination:
            i = str(i)
            i = i.replace("[", "")
            i = i.replace("]", "")
            i = i.replace("'", "")
            i = i.replace(" ", "")
            i = i.replace(",", "")
            i = i.replace("(", "")
            i = i.replace(")", "")
        
            print(i)
```

Example:

```
high = int(input("Enter highest value: "))
length = int(input("Enter amount of loops: "))

findCombonation(high,length)
```

Output:

```
Enter highest value: 4
Enter amount of loops: 3
012
013
014
023
024
034
123
124
134
234
```

[Itertools combinations syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Comment: a straightforward function would be better, but there's alot of things that seem to be redundant.

Comment: Thank your for your answer, but I really want to understand the function behind it, because I need to implement something using this technique in a larger project. I don't want to use a workaround like that, because the code could get too slow.

Comment: The variable called "high" is the equivalent to "i" in your code and "length" is the represents the N amount of nested loops. To implement this code just copy and paste it from "def" to "print(i)" and call it by typing findCombonation(i,N).

Comment: I understood that, but I want to understand how the function "combination" is actually working. I'm now trying to understand the code in the itertools library. Maybe I'll get what I'm searching for.